# Filtering another form based on fixed value

Tags: vba, ms-access, filter

Having issues with the below code when I try and add a 2nd condition which is looking for a fixed text string in the Status field.  Error is 2465 "Can't fing the field 'l1' referred to in your expression.

```
Private Sub Work_In_Progress_Click()
    Dim strFilter As String
    strFilter = "[Category] =" & Chr(39) & Me.Category.value & Chr(39) And [Status] = "work In Progress"
    Forms("f_ADb_Changes").Filter = strFilter
    Forms("f_ADb_Changes").FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `And` is literal text that needs to be between quotes and concatenated to variables
2. text parameter `work In Progress` needs apostrophe delimiters
3. apostrophes for Category parameter okay assuming Category is a text field as well
4. using `.Value` is okay but unnecessary since it is default property of data controls
5. can just type an apostrophe within literal string instead of concatenating `Chr(39)`

```
    strFilter = "[Category] ='" & Me.Category & "' And [Status] = 'work In Progress'"
```